# Webpack: How to compile all less files in a project

Tags: less, webpack

I use webpack for JS and now I want to use it for styles. I have a lot of styles in different folders and i want to compile them all without requiring each of them mannaully. The question is how to gather all the `.less` files in the folders and compile them via `less-loader`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some workaround using [require.context](http://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html#require-context).

First you need to create a js file in the root of the styles folder if you don't have one.

**Use this code if you use css or less and always extract them**

```
require.context('./', true, /(\.less$)|(\.css$)/);
```

First argument is relative path to folder in which webpack should search for the files, second tells that it should search in subfolders and the last one is regexp of the extension of the files that webpack should require. Then you need to requre this file or use it as entry point. This works if you use [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) but doesn't work otherwise.

**Using styles without extracting them to style separate file**

The example above doesn't work if you don't extract them because webpack generate modules with styles but doesn't execute them. This is complete example that works in both cases:

```
(function (requireContext) {
    return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
} (require.context('../', true, /(\.less$)|(\.css$)/)));
```

Comment: I really wonder, how to do that in v3: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context

Answer (score 3):

This isn't how webpack is meant to work, really. If you really want to do this, grunt/gulp is going to be a better choice.

Webpack's require mechanism ensures you build only the CSS you need for any given entry point, and gives you dependency management as well. If you do want to use webpack, but don't want to use the style-loader to insert them into the DOM etc., you can use the [Extract Text plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/) to build your compiled CSS into a separate file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe it is possible to do the following: create less file and use webpack's require to search all the less files and then require this single file which requires all the others and then use Extract Text Plugin?

Comment: @aspirisen You could write a custom loader or plugin to do something along those lines, but I think it would be easiest to use Grunt or Gulp to create the single LESS file first, then `require` that in your webpack build (and optionally use the Extract Text plugin). The idea of 'compile all the files in this directory' is much more suited to grunt/gulp than to webpack.